# Sending information to a prompt in a shell

Tags: shell, unix, automation

I use a CLI that starts a prompt in my shell. However, I usually end up typing the same commands at the prompt. Is there a way to manually automate the starting of the CLI and then send input in one go?

Here is an example: I type `spotify` to start my music client.
I see:

```
Type help to see commands.
> list
These are your playlists
1. ...
2. ...
```

(some lines omitted) where ">" is a prompt I am typing at. I want my script to type `list` for me then `play` and then `quit` and then start a script which plays my iTunes library. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: If this is a Windows based, application, please add a tag to indicate that else if it Linux/Unix, please add tag for that. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, should have specified. UNIX-like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) is what I was looking for. It's a UNIX testing and automation tool for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement "macro recording". For example, if you type "startrec", the CLI could save all subsequent commands, e.g. "list", "play" and "quit". The you type "stoprec spotify", which stores the command list under the title "spotify". next time when you type "spotify" your CLI could find it in the macro list, and replay the command sequence.

Comment: Could I do this with a program like `ttyrec`?

Comment: Maybe, although I don't have experience with ttyrec. If you are writing a real, compiled program (e.g. in C/C++), then adding this functionality by hand is easy. If we are talking about a shell script, then something like ttyrec could come useful.

Comment: I just tried doing it with `ttyrec`, but that's more of a screencast recorder than something that can actually perform an action. I don't know any C/C++ and wouldn't know how to implement something like that either.